# MRTG reseting a particular log file

Tags: mrtg

Through my MRTG I am trying to monitor my `CPU Load` and `Disk usage`. I am generating 2 graphs, the 2 respective  log files are **xband-disk.log** file, containing hard disk statistics and **xband.cpusum.log** file, containing cpu usage.

The problem is with xband-disk.log file. Every 5 minutes, MRTG renames the "xband-disk.log" file to an "xband-disk.old" file, and then creates a **NEW** xband-disk.log file, instead of inserting new statistic in the old one.

Say, for example, I started MRTG at 12 PM. So at 12 PM, MRTG will generated a new log file for CPU and Harddisk, and each will contain only a single non-zero entry at the top of file.

At this point of time, there is no ".old" file. Now, after 5 mins, that is at 12:05 PM, when MRTG will again log new statistics, it will "insert" the new statistic at the top of the the CPU file, **BUT NOT** in the Harddisk log file. It will rename the xband-disk.log file to xband-disk.old, and will create a new xband-disk.log file with no non-zero statistic at all (just like the one it crated at 12 PM), and will insert the 12:05 statistic in it.
Again at 12:10 PM, MRTG will rename the xband-disk.log file to xband-disk.old, overwriting the old xband-disk.log file, and will again create a new xband-disk.log file.

This is happening only for the xband-disk.log file. The xband.cpusum.log file is perfect, MRTG is not recreating it every 5 mins, its inserting the new statistic like it should. Though it does creates an old file for cpusum also, but creation of an old file for some targets is necessary for the working of MRTG, so nothing abnormal about it.

---

Here is my MRTG.cfg file

> ########## ################
>
> RunAsDaemon: Yes
>   Interval: 5
>   WriteExpires: Yes
>   WorkDir:/var/www/html
>   Options[*]:bits,growright
>
>   WithPeak[*]:wmy
>   Forks:4
>   kilo[*]: 1024
>
>   YLegend[*]:Kilo Bits/Sec.
>   Logdir: /etc/mrtg/log
>   LoadMIBS:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.txt
>
> ########## ################
>
> Target[xband.cpusum]:ssCpuRawUser.0&ssCpuRawUser.0:xgen-m@localhost + ssCpuRawSystem.0&ssCpuRawSystem.0:xgen-m@localhost + ssCpuRawNice.0&ssCpuRawNice.0:xgen-m@localhost
>   RouterUptime[xband.cpusum]: xgen-m@localhost 
>   MaxBytes[xband.cpusum]: 100
>   Title[xband.cpusum]: CPU LOAD
>   PageTop[xband.cpusum]: Active CPU Load %
>   Unscaled[xband.cpusum]: ymwd
>   ShortLegend[xband.cpusum]: % 
>   YLegend[xband.cpusum]: CPU Utilization
>   Legend1[xband.cpusum]: Active CPU in % (Load)
>   Legend2[xband.cpusum]:
>   Legend3[xband.cpusum]:
>   Legend4[xband.cpusum]:
>   LegendI[xband.cpusum]:  Active
>   LegendO[xband.cpusum]:
>   Options[xband.cpusum]: growright,nopercent
>
> ##########################
>
> Target[xband-disk]: hrStorageSize.31&hrStorageUsed.31:xgen-m@localhost
>   Title[xband-disk]: Disk Partition Usage
>       PageTop[xband-disk]: Disk Partition Usage
>   MaxBytes[xband-disk]: 100
>   ShortLegend[xband-disk]: %
>   YLegend[xband-disk]: Utilization
>   LegendI[xband-disk]: Size
>   LegendO[xband-disk]: Used
>   Options[xband-disk]: gauge,growright,nopercent
>   Unscaled[xband-disk]: ymwd`

---

Here is the output of snmpwalk command is below.
As can be seen, hrStorageSize.31 is for the size of my / partition.
And hrStorageUsed.31 is for the used space of / partition.

> [root@mrtg ~]# snmpwalk -v1 -c xgen-m localhost hrStorage
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrMemorySize.0 = INTEGER: 294448 KBytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageIndex.3 = INTEGER: 3
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageIndex.6 = INTEGER: 6
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageIndex.7 = INTEGER: 7
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageIndex.10 = INTEGER: 10
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageIndex.31 = INTEGER: 31
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageIndex.35 = INTEGER: 35
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.1 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageRam
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.3 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageVirtualMemory
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.6 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageOther
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.7 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageOther
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.10 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageVirtualMemory
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.31 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageFixedDisk
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageType.35 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES::hrStorageFixedDisk
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.1 = STRING: Physical memory
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.3 = STRING: Virtual memory
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.6 = STRING: Memory buffers
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.7 = STRING: Cached memory
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.10 = STRING: Swap space
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.31 = STRING: /
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.35 = STRING: /boot
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.1 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.3 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.6 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.7 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.10 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.31 = INTEGER: 4096 Bytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.35 = INTEGER: 1024 Bytes
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.1 = INTEGER: 294448
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.3 = INTEGER: 1900072
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.6 = INTEGER: 294448
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.7 = INTEGER: 64372
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.10 = INTEGER: 1605624
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.31 = INTEGER: 1610887
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.35 = INTEGER: 101086
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.1 = INTEGER: 191792
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.3 = INTEGER: 191792
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.6 = INTEGER: 9936
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.7 = INTEGER: 64372
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.10 = INTEGER: 0
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.31 = INTEGER: 745341
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.35 = INTEGER: 19832
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationFailures.31 = Counter32: 0
>   HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationFailures.35 = Counter32: 0

---

Here is the top entries of my xband-disk.log file and xband.cpusum.log. As you can see, the xband.cpusum.log file has all the past entries, but xband-disk.log file doesn't

> [root@mrtg html]# head -n 10 *.log
>   ==> xband.cpusum.log <==
>   1334747536 94463 94463
>   1334747536 93 93 93 93
>   1334747234 91 91 91 91
>   1334747100 92 92 94 94
>   1334746800 58 58 94 94
>   1334746500 6 6 10 10
>   1334746200 1 1 1 1
>   1334745900 0 0 1 1
>   1334745600 0 0 0 0
>   1334745300 0 0 1 1
>
> ==> xband-disk.log <==
>   1334747536 1610887 745194
>   1334747536 0 0 0 0
>   1334747234 0 0 0 0
>   1334747100 0 0 0 0
>   1334746800 0 0 0 0
>   1334746500 0 0 0 0
>   1334746200 0 0 0 0
>   1334745900 0 0 0 0
>   1334745600 0 0 0 0
>   1334745300 0 0 0 0
>   [root@mrtg html]#
>   [root@mrtg html]#
>   [root@mrtg html]#

---

Here are the top entries of the .old files. As seen, xband.cpusum.old file has all entries too, but again xband-disk.old file has only single entry, since it being overwritten again and again.

> [root@mrtg html]# head -n 10 *.old
>   ==> xband.cpusum.old <==
>   1334747234 66261 66261
>   1334747234 91 91 91 91
>   1334746925 94 94 94 94
>   1334746800 58 58 94 94
>   1334746500 6 6 10 10
>   1334746200 1 1 1 1
>   1334745900 0 0 1 1
>   1334745600 0 0 0 0
>   1334745300 0 0 1 1
>   1334745000 1 1 1 1
>
> ==> xband-disk.old <==
>   1334747234 1610887 745193
>   1334747234 0 0 0 0
>   1334746925 0 0 0 0
>   1334746800 0 0 0 0
>   1334746500 0 0 0 0
>   1334746200 0 0 0 0
>   1334745900 0 0 0 0
>   1334745600 0 0 0 0
>   1334745300 0 0 0 0
>   1334745000 0 0 0 0
>   [root@mrtg html]#

Can any one please tell me what is the small mistake I am making.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but the MaxBytes is too small.  MRTG will ignore values over 100 bytes in your configuration.

Comment: OK. Can you give me a link where I can dig more deep. I definitely want to get it right, MRTG is important for me.